# Linux stuck as a Read-only file system

Tags: linux, hard-drive, linux-mint, read-only

Edit 1 - Here is the smartctl output of the command 
Benjamin Dubois suggested:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-21-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    95OCPKKHT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 682706816
Firmware Version: AX1P2C
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Oct 13 03:02:49 2016 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 113) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 208) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1775
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1104
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   075   075   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       4240
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       4219
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   122   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1093
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       2
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
185 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       936
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   059   045   040    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 28/44)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       110
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       458759
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       15163
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   059   045   040    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 28/44)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       472
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1568
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 936 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 936 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4206 hours (175 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 38 f8 01 f4 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f401f8 = 15991288

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 40 c8 7c 07 40 00      07:23:06.682  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 38 f8 01 f4 40 00      07:23:06.682  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 28 00 e8 b3 40 00      07:23:06.682  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 20 00 60 60 40 00      07:23:06.682  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      07:23:06.681  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 935 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4206 hours (175 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 68 f8 01 f4 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00f401f8 = 15991288

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 10 70 50 83 bc 40 00      07:23:06.588  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 68 f8 01 f4 40 00      07:23:02.888  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 60 f0 01 f4 40 00      07:23:02.888  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 58 e8 01 f4 40 00      07:23:02.888  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 50 e0 01 f4 40 00      07:23:02.888  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 934 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4206 hours (175 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 48 f8 01 f4 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f401f8 = 15991288

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 a0 58 80 32 0d 40 00      07:23:02.776  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 50 c8 7c 07 40 00      07:22:59.076  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 48 a8 01 f4 40 00      07:22:59.064  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 40 20 e9 f0 40 00      07:22:59.063  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 38 18 e9 f0 40 00      07:22:59.063  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 933 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4206 hours (175 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 58 f8 01 f4 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f401f8 = 15991288

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 88 b0 c8 19 0d 40 00      06:51:49.011  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 a8 d8 ee f0 40 00      06:51:48.982  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 d8 a0 58 fd 06 40 00      06:51:45.497  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 98 40 1a be 40 00      06:51:45.497  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 90 00 b4 08 40 00      06:51:45.486  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 932 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4206 hours (175 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 98 f8 01 f4 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00f401f8 = 15991288

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 f8 40 70 ee 0a 40 00      06:51:42.395  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 b0 38 20 9d 08 40 00      06:51:41.060  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 30 30 65 0d 40 00      06:51:41.051  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 28 f0 2a 36 40 00      06:51:41.048  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 28 20 90 e7 bb 40 00      06:51:41.048  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       10%      4216         1374940408
# 2  Short captive       Interrupted (host reset)      90%      4210         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      4210         1374940408
# 4  Extended captive    Completed: read failure       90%      4210         1374940408
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      4209         1374940408
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1451         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1063         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       862         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       647         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       547         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       436         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       284         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       171         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        89         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

---

Okay first off, I think this is due to a damaged hard disk. I am running Linux Mint on an HP Pavilion laptop with an ext4 file system.

This is a dual-boot and the windows 10 works completely fine. I am now posting this from win10.

The first time the error occurred I backed up the files using a live USB and ran acheck using gparted. That ran for ~7 hrs after which I decided to just kill off the process and do a clean reinstall of Mint.

So far so good, everything works until the next day and I have finished reinstalling most of my apps again when suddenly when compiling a software gives the read-only file system error again. I again run a check which corrects a few inode errors and mint reboots fine this time. This repeats a few times.

dmesg output is flooded with a PCIE port error for my wifi adapter (Realtek) which is mostly spurious (I had them on my previous installation too and had to fix it with  pci=nomsi in the grub config file. Seems to be a common problem, I have seen it elsewhere online with HP laptops and realtek adapters)The point being I can't find anything in the mess.

So coming to my questions:

- Is there any better way to refine the dmesg output? I think I should be piping it with grep but not sure about the keyword I should be using to show stuff about hard disk only.
- If the hard disk is compromised, is it possible that my win 10 installation works fine without errors? Is it possible to check if it is damaged under windows or using the live key?
- Is is it safe to run a check on my boot partition? I haven't run a check on it yet.
- Will reinstalling with ext3 make any foreseeable difference?

Sorry about the rather basic questions, I have been using linux for just over a month.

---

Comment: Options: (1) unload realtek wifi driver module (for testing), (2) look at syslog instead of dmesg (dmesg can't be arbitrarily large) and use grep, (3) use `smartctl` on the harddisk to see if anything is wrong with it, (4) take out harddisk and connect to another computer to test/fsck it. The interesting thing to find out first is of course what's actually causing the r/o remount.

Comment: dirkt: just having to tell that option (2) can't be reliable: as soon as syslog would have to report there was a disk error, it wouldn't be able to write it in a log file because the filesystem was already remounted read-only by the kernel. Or configure syslog to send logs over UDP elsewhere.

Comment: Your harddisk is overall healthy, but has bad block(s) in the Linux partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a SMART error : SMART is a standard for HDD self-diagnostic that stores information directly on the disk firmware.

Since SMART errors are stored directly in the disk firmware, they can resist a fresh install.

You can Check the smart status of a disk using the command

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdx
```

From a Linux live CD. On debian the package is called smartmontools, must be the same on mint.

I think windows does not handle the SMART protocol natively, that might be the reason the disk does not fail under Windows.

If your drive has SMART errors, google them to find if they are critical or post them here, and backup your data: your drive is most likely to fail soon...

Comment: I am backing up the data now and have posted the error log as requested. Some help interpreting it? There are a few UNC (uncorrectable) errors and a WP (write-protected) one. Is there anyway to see more thant the past five errors?

Comment: Unfortunately no : the device only holds the 5 latest logs. But you have a bunch of reallocated sectors and many more pending sectors. This means that physical sectors are destroyed and marked unusable by the drive itself. This is a sign that  the drive is dying, especially if the count increases with use.

Comment: Can I at least locate the area of the damage and remove that from the partition? Or do I need to get the hard disk replaced? This is in all probability because of a rather hard bump my laptop got and it's still under warranty period.

Comment: It is handled automatically by the hard drive, which reallocates sectors dynamically. and marks them as unuasable. So they won't be used anymore to store data. But I wouldn't use this drive anymore: it has taken physical damage, so it is not in the best condition to store data. I would change it in a store that allows me to keep the warranty.